# Lost a tag badges I had last week

Tags: support, tag-badges

Last week I had 105 in the [xsd](/questions/tagged/xsd) tag and now I have 97? I'm sure I didn't get 8 downvotes in that time.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 options:

- One or more answers were deleted (possibly together with the question they were posted on). You don't always lose reputation for that. Check the 'show removed posts' checkbox in your reputation history.
- A question was retagged, so your answer no longer counts towards that tag. Sort your answers by recent activity and see if any of the posts that used to have the tag were edited.

Comment: Thanks yes a question was deleted because the OP obviously worked at (or with) Bloomberg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916857/extending-xsd-to-support-new-parent-element

Comment: That accounts for 2 votes though, not 8. But perhaps more were deleted. I'll look into that DMCA request.

Comment: There don't appear to be any notices in the Chilling Effects clearinghouse more recently than September last year. It could be the most recent DMCA notice has not yet been uploaded.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. Is there any way I can view the "history" of this tag for my user account? By question or date? Then I'd be able to understand why and when the +/- movements occured. Thanks in advance

Comment: @MartijnPieters just for curiosity, in what conditions we don't loose reputations even if answer or question itself gets deleted.

Comment: @CRUSADER: older than 60 days and a score of 3 or higher.

Comment: @hugh: Not really; because the tag is removed you cannot easily search for the post. That's why I suggest you look at all your answers sorted by activity.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for your help so far but I really can't see anything which would account for that kind of drop in votes.

Comment: @hugh: I've also seen vote count changes for synonym merges, but that would go the other way (*more* votes all of a sudden). Sorry I cannot be of more help!